Ubuntu Docker containers not retaining the history (After stop and start command)
I have recently started playing with containers but I have noticed an issue that the history does not persist after I stop and start the container (Note:- not build it).
I also made a directory to test it. After running the stop and start container the directory is there but yet again the history is all gone. When I run history command all I see is first entry as History. The variable $HISTFILE is set to /root/.bash_history but the file is not in the given location. I even tried to create the .bash_history with no luck funny thing is even though history command showed me history (previous run commands) there was nothing being written in this manually created file.
Anyone faced this issue in the past ?. Any help would be appreciated. My aim is to just retain the history until I destroy the container / retain it after I stop or start the same container.
Additional details:-
Its Linux container (I am running docker engine on Ubuntu).
Also the container's OS itself is Ubuntu.

Are you running Ubuntu inside a docker container or a Docker container inside Ubuntu? what is the host OS? Docker containers are supposed to start fresh every time you start them. Are you using the -rm option when you start the Ubuntu container? Edit your question with the additional information.

@user68186 I did add additional information. I don't use the -rm option, what does it do and how will it help in my case ?.

I googled a bit. It looks like the bash history is not saved by default. There are some work around on the net I can't tell you which to use.

I solved this exact problem by applying the solution found here: http://aloop.org/2012/01/19/flush-commands-to-bash-history-immediately/
Summary:
The history of commands is not flushed after every command by default. When docker exists, it may not flush the history to file since related process can be killed too qickly
Solution: Flush commands to bash history immediately, like this:
Just include this code:
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
to your .bashrc file and reload it with ". ~/.bashrc" or "source ~/.bashrc".
This will create a bash environment variable carrying a command. "The value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt" as bash man page states.
